multiple criteria formula at once

I have a question on putting in few criteria in a IF formula to get an outcome.

Criteria 1 - if tasked date = schedule date ---> urgent
Criteria 2 - if tasked date > 1 day later than schedule date but over 4.30pm ---> last min
Criteria 3 - if schedule date > task date ---> normal


What is the question exactly? If you can put multiple if in one formula in excel? yes. example= =IF(C2=D2, "Urgent", IF(AND(C2>D2+1, HOUR(C2)>=16.5), "Last Min", IF(D2>C2, "Normal", "Check Dates")))
Now, in your post scheduled date ---> urgent which schedule date? the arrival or the departure?
Also, it would be great if you could share a google sheet link or something to help dive in.
